# Find any special characters in a string

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I still struggle big time to `match` a `string` that contains the special characters (punctuation, underlines, etc). How can I make it work with patterns?

```
if string.match(mystr, '???') ~= nil then
  print('Invalid characters.')
end
```

Comment: Heads up, Lua doesn't have a standard regex engine - it has something called [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1).

Comment: `if string.find(mystr, '%p') then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character sets `[...]` are your friend here.

```
.*[@!#$%^&*()?<>].*
```

Comment: In this case, isn't it a better choice to negate **anything that is not alpha or numeric**? (space characters must also be avoided).

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino in which case, a negated character set is probably best. `[^whatever characters you allow]`

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino try `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`